# php regular expression to remove unwanted code

Tags: php, regex

The editor I am using is adding extraneous coding that I would like to remove via php before writing to the database.
The code looks like this:

```
<img style="width: 250px;" src="files/school-big.jpg" data-cke-saved-src="files/school-big.jpg" alt="">
<img style="width: 250px;" src="files/firemen.jpg" data-cke-saved-src="files/firemen.jpg" alt="">
```

What I need to get rid of is the data-cke-saved-src="files/image-name". My understanding of regex is somewhere below weak so how would I build a regex to grab the image name without grabbing the end of the line or the rest of the content?
Thank you kindly,

Comment: why regex? this is very easily removed with JS

Comment: Isn't it easier to remove it with jQuery? `$('img').removeAttr('data-cke-saved-src')`

Comment: I just figured as I was cleaning things with php already I might as well keep it within that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = preg_replace('#\s(data-cke-saved-src)="[^"]+"#', '', $data);
```

Or do it in jQuery before going into PHP with this:

```
$('img').removeAttr('data-cke-saved-src')
```

Comment: I was attempting to use str_replace instead of preg_replace, that is where I was going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding and using this function:

```
/*
*I am assuming you get all the data in a single variable.
*/

function remove_data_cke($text) {
    // Get all data-cke-saved-src="..." tags from the html.
    $result = array();
    preg_match_all('|data-cke-saved-src="[^"]*"|U', $text, $result);

    // Replace all occurances with an empty string.
    foreach($result[0] as $data_cke) {
        $text = str_replace($data_cke, '', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated?  If you must do this with a regex, you can do the whole job in one `preg_replace()` call like [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31766138/20938).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to easily remove the attribute:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
   $img->removeAttribute('data-cke-saved-src');
}
```